# Forcing a custom message box on error, can't work with runtime errors?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, runtime

I'm trying to create a "library" of sorts for errors that pop up so people using my spreadsheets know immediately what's gone wrong. This works fine for standard errors but I cannot get it to trip on Runtime errors. In this case, Runtime Error 53 is occurring, I think because it is trying to delete a temporary file that was not successfully saved (which is what my message box will display.

Note - I am not trying to SOLVE this error, I've deliberately made it trip so that users know what's gone wrong. I'm trying to make the given message box come up when the Runtime Error 53 happens.

So this macro works, as it's just a standard 1004 error:

```
 Sub ReportSaveandEmail()
   Dim IsCreated As Boolean
   Dim i As Long
   Dim PdfFile As String, Title As String
   Dim OutlApp As Object
   On Error GoTo Whoa

 '-> Sub deleted 

Whoa:
Dim OutPut As Integer   
Select Case Err.Number
    Case 1004 'Search error'
        OutPut = MsgBox("Found an error (#1004).  This error usually occurs when the macro is searching for a file or folder that doesn't exist. Please check your code.", vbCritical, "File not found")
End Select
End Sub
```

But this error, a runtime, doesn't trip. I just get a standard Excel message box: "Micosoft Visual Basic | Run-time Error 53 | File Not Found"

```
 Sub ReportSaveandEmail()
   Dim IsCreated As Boolean
   Dim i As Long
   Dim PdfFile As String, Title As String
   Dim OutlApp As Object
   On Error GoTo Whoa

 '-> Sub deleted 

 Whoa:
     Dim OutPut As Integer    
     Select Case Err.Number
         Case 53 'Can't find file to delete'
        OutPut = MsgBox("Found an error (#53).  This error usually occurs when the macro tries to delete a temporary file that was not successfully created.", vbCritical, "Temp File not found")
End Select      
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: your code is running within the runtime. it is not unusual that you cannot use language constructs to handle runtime errors.

Comment: Is there any way at all to trigger my message box when a runtime error is detected?

Comment: Not generally. The message box is created by the runtime, so when it crashes, there's no way to execute code when you are in that state.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response. It only occurs when I force a 1004 error in this case so hopefully they will just know to fix the 1004 and not have the 53 come up at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete it does not demonstrate how you set the error.

Deliberately raising error 53 appears to work as it should.

```
Sub ReportSaveandEmail()

    On Error GoTo Whoa
    Err.Raise 1004
    Err.Raise 53
    Exit Sub

Whoa:

    Select Case Err.number
        Case 1004 'Search error'
            MsgBox "Found an error (#1004).  This error usually occurs when the macro is searching for a file or folder that doesn't exist. Please check your code.", vbCritical, "File not found"
            Resume Next

        Case 53 'Can't find file to delete'
            MsgBox "Found an error (#53).  This error usually occurs when the macro tries to delete a temporary file that was not successfully created.", vbCritical, "Temp File not found"
            Resume Next

    End Select

End Sub
```

Notice once you raise 1004 you have to clear or resume to allow 53 to be trapped.